# Linux grep command

Tags: linux, grep

Can I use grep command to look for all the lines in a file that have"abc" in them, but exclude the lines that end in say "xyz"?

Eg grep 'abc' fileName (some way to exclude all lines ending in "xyz")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat sample.csv 
abc, xyz
abc,1
abc,2
abc,3,xyz
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ grep abc sample.csv |grep -v "xyz$"
abc,1
abc,2
```

The explanation of -v:

```
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
```

If you can use `awk`, just check the patterns:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ awk '/abc/ && !/xyz$/' sample.csv 
abc,1
abc,2
```

Comment: @Hello I seldom advertise the advantage of my solutions, but have a look at the performance overhead. `sed` and `awk` solutions need to iterate over the file just once while the above `grep` solution is doing it twice. What if you have `3` or more conditions? Would you iterate over the file so much times? `awk '/abc/&&!/xyz$/'` is **the** way to go. You need to get fluent with such simple `awk` invocations the same as with `grep`

Comment: glad it helps, as hek2mgl said awk and sed have better performances on solving such problems, and thats why i provide awk solution as well

Answer (score 4):

`awk` fit's pretty good for such cases:

```
awk '/abc/ && !/xyz$/' input
```

*use awk!* :)

Comment: awk is definitely the right solution for this. but I think I might say that a lot... :-)

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, you did! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use two `grep` commands piped together. The first matches `abc`, the second removes the ones that end with `xyz`.

```
grep abc filename | grep -v 'xyz$'
```